# HTML form not passing checkbox value trough $_POST in php file

Tags: php, html, post, checkbox

I have a form in HTML with some checkboxes and I want to send an email with the selected checkboxes in the body, the problem is that the "text" fields are passing to the PHP variables, but the checkboxes values are always set to uncheck when I test it on the PHP file:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="c-checkbox-list">
        <div class="c-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox"   name="checkbox1citadina" id="checkbox1citadina" value="checkbox1citadina" class="form-control c-check" >
            <label for="checkbox1citadina">
                <span></span>
                <span class="check"></span>
                <span class="box"></span> Citadina
            </label>
        </div>
```

PHP:

```
$reservas_bicicletas = ''; 

if (isset($_POST['checkbox1citadina'])) {
    $reservas_bicicletas .= "Citadina: checked\n";
} else {
    $reservas_bicicletas .= "Citadina: unchecked\n";
}

echo $reservas_bicicletas;

$reservas_bicicletas always retrieves the else value.
```

Need help guys, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is sent through a `form`?

Comment: Where is your `form` tag?

Comment: Are your checkboxes inside (between) `<form>` tags?

Comment: yes is sent through a form, method post

Comment: yes they're RST

Comment: In its current form your question is not a [mcve] of the problem you are describing and that greatly reduces anyone's ability to pinpoint your mistake/error and advise/answer the question. Please provide more context to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

remove **c-check**

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="c-checkbox-list">
<div class="c-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox"   name="checkbox1citadina" id="checkbox1citadina" value="checkbox1citadina" class="form-control " >
<label for="checkbox1citadina">
<span></span>
<span class="check"></span>
<span class="box"></span> Citadina</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Yes, can you explain me why? thks

Answer (score 0):

Basically i have this (i shorted out the form because there are too many elements):

HTML:

```
<form name="quick_booking" id="quick_booking" method="post" action="assets/reserva-bicicletas.php">

<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="c-checkbox-list">
<div class="c-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox"   name="checkbox1citadina" id="checkbox1citadina" value="checkbox1citadina" class="form-control " >
<label for="checkbox1citadina">
<span></span>
<span class="check"></span>
<span class="box"></span> Citadina</label>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn c-theme-btn c-btn-uppercase btn-lg c-btn-bold c-btn-square">Reservar</button>

</form>
```